# Setting height to an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried this:

```
$('#my_ifr').css('height', '5px !important');
```

and this:

```
$('#my_ifr').height(5);
```

But the size remains the same. When I write:

```
$('#my_ifr').height();
```

in cosole, I get 5, but when I inspect the element in Goog

Comment: What does your html look like? (skeleton please :))

Comment: @JeroenMoons I have a simple html with tinymce in it.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle of your problem?

Comment: @JeroenMoons http://jsfiddle.net/GwkRQ/60/

Comment: what is it that you want to set its height to 5px? the white text area in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this, it's working fine...

```
$('#iframeID').css({'height':'500px'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/GwkRQ/98/

But, you want to increase the tinymce height means,

you use like this,

```
tinyMCE.init({
...
height : "500"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set his `height` attribute

```
$('#my_ifr').attr('height', '5');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
$('#my_ifr').css('height', '500');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkifloaded () {
    if ($('#mce_0_ifr').length > 0) {
        $('#mce_0_ifr').css({'height': '5px'});
        window.clearInterval(intid);
    }
}

var intid = setInterval(checkifloaded, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GwkRQ/163/

Answer (score 0):

Both answers (@yogi & @Mihai Iorga) are rigth, but looking your jsfiddle.... a few things to comment:

You are not triggering the function... add:

```
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

(Is the same...)

Now... Another thing is in you jsfiddle, there's no **iframe#my_ifr**

---

Try this update: http://jsfiddle.net/GwkRQ/94/

```
$(function() {
    // Not Valid
    //$('#mce_0_ifr').height(5);

    // Valid - by @yogi
    $('#my_ifr').css('height', '500');

    // Valid - by @Mihai Iorga only if no attr was previulsy set
    // but be carefull because pre-defined element.style or css rule
    // will overright the atribute (attr)
    $('#my_ifr').attr('height', '5');
    // That is, the iframe will have 500 and not 5
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey You need to load the contents of that Iframe before setting the css height property.
Otherwise it will remain undefined and you can not change the height property..

WOrking Code

```
setInterval(function(){if(typeof($('#mce_0_ifr').css('height'))=='undefined'){}else{$('#mce_0_ifr').css('height','50px');}},0);
```

[FIDLLE WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v3ggd/)